# How to restart Azure Web App using Jenkins after Deploy?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have completed CICD setup in Jenkins and build is deployed to Azure when code is pushed. I have to restart Web App after deployment but I don't get ready made available task in Jenkins in Add post-build action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a different plugin to be able to do that. Check out the [Azure App Service Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+App+Service+Plugin) from the Jenkins marketplace.